# Python log rotate file lock error

Tags: python, logging, log-rotation

I am trying to implement a python log rotation.

I have the following code to set up my logs:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("Log Rotate")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#set up file logging output
fh = logging.FileHandler(log)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#set up console output
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

#set up log rotate
lr = RotatingFileHandler(log, maxBytes=3000, backupCount=2)

# add the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(lr)
```

When this is run, i am getting an error that the process cannot access the file because it is being used...

So to me, I think this is because it is trying to create a new log whilst it's writing to it, so windows is preventing it.

Is there a way around this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing the same - I have several tasks logging to the same log at the same time (I include PID, so I know what's up).  Once a day I do a manual rollover of the logs using a Powershell script (well, I had one already) and it occasionally fails to do anything, as the Python log is open.

I'm looking for a way to temporarily close the log, then re-open it.   That's an IO hit but it's a price I'm prepared to pay.  Some of the Python stuff I'm running takes 90 minutes... big downloads.